# Is there a way to GROUP BY accent insensitive in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to perform a **GROUP BY** statement in ORACLE DBMS, when I found that there are some variables that are accent sensitive like CITY.

For example, lets say that I want to make the following SQL request:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(*)
FROM restaurant
WHERE pricing='High'
GROUP BY city;
```

Then my output would be

```
-----------------
|CITY  |COUNT(*)|
-----------------
|Bogota|      10|
-----------------
|Bogotá|       5|
-----------------
```

When the output I want is :

```
-----------------
|CITY  |COUNT(*)|
-----------------
|Bogota|      15|
-----------------
```

I want to know if there is a way to make the **GROUP BY** statement accent insensitive with out modifying the tables.

Comment: Check out collations.

Comment: Unfortunately I don´t have the permissions to alter tables in the database and from what I understand from collations is that you need to alter it in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a recent version you can use [COLLATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COLLATE-Operator.html#GUID-1B8CE3B0-77FC-455C-8400-6F81CF188D7B):

```
SELECT city COLLATE UCA0700_DUCET_AI as city, COUNT(*)
FROM restaurant
WHERE pricing='High'
GROUP BY city COLLATE UCA0700_DUCET_AI;
```

```
CITY    COUNT(*)
------  --------
Bogota  15
```

This will also cover different case, as well as accents.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f77116ea7bd2b1a852226de74351d7e2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a coding without accents.
NB you will need to convert it wherever it is used in the SELECT otherwise you will get an error.

```
USE GROUP BY CONVERT( City, 'US7ASCII' )
```

NB If this is a large table and/or you will be querying it this way often you should consider creating an index to speed up the query.

```
CREATE INDEX index_city_no_accents ON table_name ( CONVERT( City, 'US7ASCII' ) );
```

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thank you, however it's important to mention that you need to add ``` CONVERT( city, 'US7ASCII')``` In all the parts that city is used other wise it wont work, at least that's how it is for me

Comment: Also maybe worth noting the Oracle [discourages the use of `convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CONVERT.html#GUID-C8BA0657-61C8-4964-A4CB-9292390853F6).